# MySQL query to search for tags of a specific name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a query to search for tags for a certain user name.

What I'm trying to achieve is to order the name by tag.

I have a page that displays images for a certain user, the user upload the pictures to his page and then he cant display them in a page

```
(pictures.php?user=John%Doe&tag=waterfall)
```

Then I set a variable with the value of the parameters in the URL

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$tag= $_GET['tag'];
```

In my database the table is formed like this (the picture is set with link so I will just put an example link):

```
user_name    | picture               | tag1      | tag2      | tag3   | tag4
John Doe     | example.com/picture1  | waterfall | jungle    | null   | Green
Carl Johnson | example.com/picture4  | null      | waterfall | forest | null
Joseph       | example.com/picture14 | street    | car       | people | null
```

They all have different pictures with different tags

I tried to query it like this

```
SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE name = '$user' AND tag1= '$tag' OR tag2 = '$tag' OR tag3 = '$tag' OR tag4 = '$tag'
```

This is the query that achieved the closest of what I want the problem is that outputs not specifically what I want

The output (I have a table to display the data and it goes like this):

```
John Doe     | example.com/picture1 | waterfall
Carl Johnson | example.com/picture4 | waterfall
```

The thing is that it displays all of the names that have the tag that I want to order and I just want to get the output for the queried user name

If you guys understand what I want to achieve and can help, Thank you very much!

Comment: this is a bad db structure you should move tags to their own table

Comment: I know but this is an example. I have all the tags in a separated table and I have them with relations I just created an example to get to the point :3

Comment: so its not what you actually use, so any answer will be pointless, im confused.

Comment: This was to make it simpler, instead of saying i got the tags in a different and complicating the question which is already somewhat confusing so i found a way to make it simpler. the important thing is that i already got it solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `or` logic.  It's included other names if those tags match.  Easy to resolve, just use parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_user 
WHERE (name = '$user') AND 
    (tag1= '$tag' OR tag2 = '$tag' OR tag3 = '$tag' OR tag4 = '$tag')
```

---

Or perhaps you could use `in`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_user 
WHERE name = '$user' AND '$tag' IN (tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4)
```

Comment: That is it! I used the first example. Both of them work perfectly. Never thought it was so simple, I also tried the IN clause but I was messing the query up. Well  thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a parenthesis around the tags. The WHERE clause is incorrect

```
SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE name = '$user' AND (tag1= '$tag' OR tag2 = '$tag' OR tag3 = '$tag' OR tag4 = '$tag')
```

Comment: The other answer already answered my question. But thank you for the answer also. I hope you don't mind me for accepting him as the right answer.